# Nativescript Angular iOS crashing after splash screen (started randomly)

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Today, randomly, my app stopped running on iOS anymore. I have been working on it daily for weeks and nothing has changed this morning. Works fine on Android. On iOS it shows the splashscreen like normal and then just quit out. There are no errors shown in the console. I am using Sidekick cloud build for iOS. I am running on a physical device. In fact it does not run on my iPod, but it will run fine on my iPad.

Has anyone had this problem? Is there a reason no errors are visible?

> SpringBoard: Forcing crash report of  (reason: 1, description:
>   org.nativescript.myapp failed to scnene-create after 4.77s (launch
>   took 15.23s of total time limit 10.00s))

Comment: Have you tried running your app from XCode? XCode's debugger will sometimes show things that the terminal may exclude.

Comment: I'm using sidekick cloud builds, no access to xcode. Don't have a Mac.

Comment: I was able to borrow a mac and watched the console in XCode. This is the error I am getting:
`SpringBoard: Forcing crash report of <FBApplicationProcess: 0x18c19a40; myapp; pid: 368> (reason: 1, description: org.nativescript.myapp failed to scnene-create after 4.77s (launch took 15.23s of total time limit 10.00s))`

Comment: check for the space available on device.

Comment: ~12GB available still

Comment: are you using a webview in your app? which version of NS you are using?

Comment: is it working for you after reducing the loading time?

Comment: Honestly, I don't really know how I can reduce my loading time.

Answer (score 1):

Found some insights for this and looks like it is crashing because you are spending too much time doing CPU work on the splash screen.

iOS will kill your app if it takes it too much time to load.

The crash report for this would have an exception code of 8badf00d(this is in Hexadecimal) and it will also say “failed to scene-create in time”.
That is exactly you are also getting. 
So try not to load to my things on app initilization and get away from Splash screen as soon as possible.